# Unlock Table from forUpdate lock

Tags: knex.js

I'm using "for update" to prevent race issues in my selection. You mention that The locks are saved in a table called "tableName_lock" with single column called is_locked that you need to set to 0 in order to release the lock.

My table is called requests, so I created a table called "requests_lock" and created a column called is_locked. that table never gets updated when I use for update. Is there anything I'm missing here?

```
bookshelf.knex.transaction(function(trx) {

 var query = bookshelf.knex('requests').transacting(trx).forUpdate().select('requests.id', 'requests.CreatedTime').then(function (user_roles) {
            console.log('user_friends: %j', user_roles);  
}).then(trx.commit)
  .catch(trx.rollback);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

`SELECT FOR UPDATE` locks the selected rows until the transaction ends https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-select.html#SQL-FOR-UPDATE-SHARE. The rows selected for update cannot be selected by any other db connection until the transaction, which locked the rows is ended.

There is no separate locking table used.

The `migrationTableName_lock` table mentioned in question is used only to prevent migrations from being ran from multiple different clients at the same time and it has nothing to do with `.forUpdate()`.